# Convert CreateLSN of DBCC LOGINFO into time

Tags: sql-server-2008, functions

If I run the undocumented  `DBCC LOGINFO` against my database one of the fields returned is CreateLSN.  This is the LSN in the format 1629000000070500011 at the time the VLF was created.  Now it is a long time later and the auto grow values of Disk Usage report are long gone.  I want to convert the LSN to a date/time

For a one off solution I tried this

```
select sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time ( convert(binary,1629000000070500011) )
```

But I get the error

> Invalid object name 'cdc.lsn_time_mapping'

I feel like I am missing something simple, but it is alluding me.

[sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-cdc-map-lsn-to-time-transact-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LSN is incremented each time a *modification* is made to the database, irrespective of *when* the modification was made.

`sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time` relies on the current database having Change Data Capture enabled, which automatically creates several objects in the cdc schema.  The definition of `fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time` shows this:

```
create function [sys].[fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time]              
(                                                       
    @lsn        binary(10)                                  
)                                                       
returns datetime
with returns null on null input
as                                                  
begin                                                   
    declare @lsn_end_time datetime

    select @lsn_end_time = tran_end_time                            
    from [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping]
    where start_lsn = @lsn

    return @lsn_end_time                                        
end
```

So, unless the current database has the `cdc.lsn_time_mapping` object (I'm unsure if this is a view or a table) present, the function will not work.

The notes in the docs page you linked says:

> This function can be used to determine the time that a change was committed based upon the __$start_lsn value returned in the row of change data.

I'm extrapolating that the function actually returns pre-recorded LSN-to-timestamp tuples, instead of actually converting an LSN into a timestamp.

[@RemusRusanu](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/708/remus-rusanu) has an excellent writeup about LSNs on [his blog](http://rusanu.com/2012/01/17/what-is-an-lsn-log-sequence-number/)